# Jest - mock function in 'child_process' package

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests and which to mock the 'exec' method in package 'child_process'.

**__mocks__/child_process.js**

```
const child_process = jest.genMockFromModule('child_process');
child_process.exec = jest.fn()

module.exports = child_process;
```

**This is the test file:**

```
const fs = require('fs-extra'),
      child_process = require('child_process'),
      runCassandraMigration = require('../../lib/runCassandraMigration.js')

const defaultArguments = () => {
  return {
    migration_script_path: './home',
    logger: {
      error: function () {}
    }
  };
}

jest.mock("fs-extra")
jest.mock("child_process")

describe('Running cassandra migration tests', function () {
  describe('successful flow', function () {
    it('Should pass without any errors ', async function () {
        let args = defaultArguments();
        let loggerSpy = jest.spyOn(args.logger, 'error')

        fs.remove.mockImplementation(() => {Promise.resolve()})
        child_process.exec.mockImplementation(() => {Promise.resolve()})

        await runCassandraMigration(args.migration_script_path, args.logger)
    });
  });
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
child_process.exec.mockImplementation is not a function
```

**The module I test**

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const promisify = require('util').promisify
const execAsync = promisify(require('child_process').exec)

module.exports = async (migration_script_path, logger) => {
  try {
    console.log()
    const {stdout, stderr} = await execAsync(`cassandra-migration ${migration_script_path}`)
    logger.info({stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr}, 'Finished runing cassandra migration')
    await fs.remove(migration_script_path)
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e, 'Failed to run cassandra migration')
    throw Error()
  }
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A late... *answer*?...

Yesterday I got the same error and the problem was that I wasn't calling `jest.mock('child_process')` in my test file.

Jest [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) says that when mocking Node's core modules calling `jest.mock('child_process')` is required. I see you do this but for some reason it is not working (maybe Jest is not hoisting it to the top).

Anyways, with Jest version 24.9.0 I don't get the `child_process.exec.mockImplementation is not a function` error but get some other errors because your test is not well implemented.

To make your test work I:

Added `info: function () {},` inside `logger`

Updated the implementation of `exec` to `child_process.exec.mockImplementation((command, callback) => callback(null, {stdout: 'ok'}))` 
And also (not necessary for the test to pass) updated the implementation of `fs.remove` to `fs.remove.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve())`

Like this:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra'),
      child_process = require('child_process'),
      runCassandraMigration = require('./stack')

const defaultArguments = () => {
  return {
    migration_script_path: './home',
    logger: {
      info: function () {},
      error: function () {}
    }
  };
}

jest.mock("fs-extra")
jest.mock("child_process")

describe('Running cassandra migration tests', function () {
  describe('successful flow', function () {
    it('Should pass without any errors ', async function () {
        let args = defaultArguments();
        let loggerSpy = jest.spyOn(args.logger, 'error')

        fs.remove.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve())
        child_process.exec.mockImplementation((command, callback) => callback(null, {stdout: 'ok'}))

        await runCassandraMigration(args.migration_script_path, args.logger)
    });
  });
});
```