# Jest: child_process.exec.mockImplentation is not a function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, child-process

I have a function that uses the `child_process.exec` function:

```
//serverUtils.js:
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec);

  async getUpstreamRepo() {
    try {
      const forkConfig = (await exec('git remote get-url upstream')).stdout;
      let upstreamRepo = forkConfig.replace('git@github.com:', '');
      upstreamRepo = upstreamRepo.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '');
      return upstreamRepo;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  },
```

[After looking at this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57731728/6637004), I tried to mock the exec call like so:

```
//serverUtils.test.js:
const child_process = require('child_process');
jest.mock('child_process')
describe('Test Class', () => {
    ....
    it('check upstream repo', async () => {      

    child_process.exec.mockImplentation(jest.fn().
        mockReturnValueOnce('git@github.com:mock/url.git'))

    await expect(serverScript.getUpstreamRepo()).
        resolves.toEqual('mock/url.git');
    });
 }
```

However, I get `child_process.exec.mockImplentation is not a function`
As the linked post explains, "[Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) says that when mocking Node's core modules calling jest.mock('child_process') is required." -- which I clearly do.

Answer (score 5):

The error you are seeing is because you are calling `mockImplentation` instead of `mockImplementation`. Unfortunately, when you correct that typo the test still will not pass.

This is because you are calling `promisify` on `exec` method, allowing it to be used as a promise. What [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) does under the hood is transform from an asynchronous callback based function (where the callback is placed at last parameter and is called with error as first parameter and data as second) to a promise based function.

So, in order for the `promisify` method to work, you will have to mock the [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) method so that it calls the callback parameter in order for the promise to resolve.

Also, note that you are reading the `stdout` parameter from the result of the `exec` call, so in the returned data you will have to send an object with that property.

Having all that into account:

```
it('check upstream repo', async () => {
    child_process.exec.mockImplementation((command, callback) => {
        callback(null, { stdout: 'git@github.com:mock/url.git' });
    });

    await expect(serverScript.getUpstreamRepo()).
        resolves.toEqual('mock/url.git');
});
```

Another posible solution is to directly mock the `promisify` method:

```
jest.mock('util', () => ({
    promisify: jest.fn(() => {
        return jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ stdout: 'git@github.com:mock/url.git' });
    })
}));

describe('Test Class', () => {
    it('check upstream repo', async () => {
        await expect(serverScript.getUpstreamRepo()).
            resolves.toEqual('mock/url.git');
    });
});
```